# A question on a property of geometric morphisms related to locales.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Is the "localic reflection" of a geometric morphism between topoi the same thing as its "localic part"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They both refer to the hyperconnected–localic factorisation of geometric morphisms.

Comment: Thanks! So when authors generalize results from locales to toposes and say "a geometric morphism has property P if its localic part has property P" what they mean is that the left adjoint $L$ of the inclusion of the category of locales to the category of toposes has property P?

Comment: Not at all. They mean what they say.

Comment: I am confused. The hyperconnected-localic factorisation you mention gives you a localic geometric morphism. And authors ask that that geometric morphism has a property P. Shouldn't that somehow restrict the definition they want to the case of locales, where that definition is known and makes sense? How else, if you don't use $L$? I am sorry if I am asking too much, but I would be really grateful if you could help me clarify this.

Comment: $L$ itself is _not_ a localic geometric morphism (or a locale), so how could it possibly have property $P$?

Comment: $L$ gives you morphisms of locales, where $P$ makes sense. I don't see any other way to restrict the property $P$ from topoi to the morphisms in the category of locales which have $P$. Most likely there is a big piece of theory that explains this that apparently I am not aware of.

Comment: $P$ is not supposed to be a property of morphisms of locales; rather $P$ is a property of localic geometric morphisms or locales. I think you need to review the definitions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello Zhen Lin. I have spent an afternoon trying to understand exactly this terminology. It is not clear to me at all. For example, a geometric morphism is called proper if the localic part of the hyperconnected-localic factorization is proper. What is it exactly, in the world of locales, that I require to be proper? I am sorry for disturbing again, even a reference to read something somewhere would be of great help.

Comment: I don't know any good reference. What you have to understand first is Grothendieck's relative point of view: a localic geometric morphism $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{S}$ is something like "a locale from the point of view of $\mathcal{S}$". Indeed, the 2-category of localic geometric morphisms $\mathcal{E} \to \mathbf{Set}$ (for variable $\mathcal{E}$) is equivalent to the 2-category of locales. But for general $\mathcal{S}$ one has to speak of "internal locales in $\mathcal{S}$".

Comment: Yes, I understand that localic geometric morphisms can be "identified" with locales. But say I have a geometric morphism at hand and I want to prove that it is proper (or P, generally). Then I have to check that "the corresponding localic geometric morphism" (given by the factorisation) is proper.  But this should be taking the verification to the world of locales (where I know what proper means - and it means something for maps, not locales themselves), right? My question is, what is this actual morphism of locales that I should be checking that has P?  Or am I completely wrong?...

Comment: A localic geometric morphism is not literally a locale, as I explained. But there is a correspondence. A localic geometric morphism $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{S}$ is proper if and only if the corresponding internal locale in $\mathcal{S}$ is proper. But one still has to define what it means for an internal locale in $\mathcal{S}$ to be proper.

Comment: Ok, this makes much more sense now, thanks. I did not know that you could call a locale proper. I will definitely have a look at this. It looks like the correct place to go is the Elephant. Thanks again very much for your help.